# In VS Code what's the difference between Quick Switch Window and Switch Window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

It seems like both commands do the same thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you release the assigned key...

- `workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow` switches to the selected window
- `workbench.action.switchWindow` keeps the popup open until press enter

See also the [version 1.14 announcement](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14#_switch-window-improvements):

> [...] a new command `workbench.action.quickSwitchWindow` was added to quickly switch between opened windows. Press and hold the modifier key to cycle through the list of windows and release all keys to open it.